# XAML XML DataBinding does not work

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a XML file like the fallowing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Course
    Title="jQueryAjax"
    BtnAddisionalResourcesTitle=""
    BtnAddisionalResourcesAddress="">
<Topic
    Tag="ff"
    Title="">

    <Lesson
      Tag=""
      Title=""
      Address=""
    />

    <!--...-->


  </Topic>

  <!--...-->
</Course>
```

And also have a label like the fallowing

```
    <Label 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                FontSize="16pt"
                FontFamily="Myriad Pro"
                >
            <Label.Content>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource CourseInfo}"
                         XPath="Title"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                         />
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
```

And a `XmlDataProvider` in between:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="CourseInfo" Source="Settings\CourseScema.xml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

but get this error as I trace using `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener`:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: '' property not `found for 'current item of collection' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=/; DataItem=null; target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to provide a root `XPath` to the `XmlDataProvider`:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="CourseInfo" Source="Settings\CourseScema.xml" XPath="Course"/>
```

Secondly, `Title` is an attribute, so you need to use:

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource CourseInfo}"
                         XPath="@Title"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                         />
```

Also, make sure your xml file's `Build Action` is set to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` is set to either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.